# Convert all uppercase Tags to Lowercase?

Tags: javascript, php, xhtml, filemaker

Is there away to convert all HTML tags from uppercase to lowercase? I am using Filemaker pro 12 to input some data into a MYSQL database which then is displayed on a PHP page on my web server. The trouble is Filemaker inserts tags for formatting in uppercase rather than lowercase. I'd like it to be displayed as below please:

**Before:**

```
<SPAN STYLE="color:#fff">My Text</SPAN> <BR/>
```

**After:**

```
<span style="color:#fff">My Text</span> <br/>
```

I'd also like to say seeing as I have got given a negative that I have tried some examples on here and none seem to have worked for me :(

I am also hosting on a Windows server if that helps at all

Comment: Would it be possible to pass the data through HTML Tidy extension? I believe it has the ability to convert tags to upper / lower case, see [documentation](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#uppercase-tags)

Comment: Thanks Dale, I have never heard of this extension. Is it a linux server related extension? I am on a windows server (will update above post to include that)

Comment: It's available on both platforms, I run a local windows server and a linux server. Here's the [PHP manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php). If you use something like wampserver(.com) you can enable it in the PHP extensions shortcuts

Comment: Thanks Dale I'll check it out now :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Filemaker inserts tags"? Are you using the GetAsCSS() function to generate the data?

Comment: If the text is in FileMaker, you could use FileMaker's Lower() function to make it lower case. You'd have to write or find a custom function to Lower only the HTML tags, though. http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/func_ref3.33.68.html#1031014

Answer (score -2):

I used pft221's suggestion and worked great!

> If the text is in FileMaker, you could use FileMaker's Lower()
>   function to make it lower case. You'd have to write or find a custom
>   function to Lower only the HTML tags, though.
>   filemaker.com/help/html/func_ref3.33.68.html#1031014 – pft221

Comment: This is not really an answer unless you explain how you managed to apply Lower() to markup only. Until you do, this is not useful to anyone else, hence -1.

Comment: unfortunately it would be only relevant to my script as there is far to much to going on in it to just paste it here. I see it as helpful as I didn't know about this function until pft221 posted it